# Обработка изменения выбранного значения

Tags: android, java

Как отслеживать изменение, что пользователь выбрал другой пункт в `Spinner`? У меня падает исключение:

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3903): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: setOnItemClickListener cannot be used with a spinner.
        at android.widget.Spinner.setOnItemClickListener(Spinner.java:257)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`setOnItemSelectedListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemSelectedListener(android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener)), Luke.